# PHPExcel with operators

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel library:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

I whant to set a formula for the C1 cell:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 5)
            ->setCellValue('B1', 6)
            ->setCellValue('C1', "=SUM(A1,B1)");
```

That works fine.

Once I change the formula to one that has + or - operators, for example:

```
    ->setCellValue('C1', "=A1-B1");
```

instead of

```
    ->setCellValue('C1', "=SUM(A1,B1)");
```

I get the following error:

***Illegal string offset 'value' in \phpexcel\PHPExcel\Calculation.php on line 2976***

and then

***Array to string conversion in \phpexcel\PHPExcel\Calculation.php on line 3010***

Looking at the Calculation.php code - I find out that it cuts the references A1 and B1 to A and B.

Any idea how to fix it? Thank you!

- Remark1: Looks like it doesn't matter but I prefer to mention that I
  have a spanish version of Excel installed on the computer.
- Remark2: In the examples I found on PHPExcel GitHub all the formulas
  don't have operators, only functions are used.

Comment: Unable to replicate: I've just tested against version 1.7.0 through 1.7.9 using your example. Is your formula really as simple as this? Can you identify where the calculation engine cuts these values from A1 and B1 to A and B?

Comment: 05FeatureDemo contains a number of formulas using operators, including `=E11+E12` as well as `=E11*0.21` and more complex formulas with operators such as `=IF(D6<>"",C6*D6,"")`

Comment: What version of PHPExcel are you using? line 2976 of Calculation.php in version 1.79 should only be accessed if you've specified a cell range (e.g. `A1:B1`), but doesn't access `value` in any way (although line 2974 does)

Comment: Concerning your last comment - that happens because of cutting the row number A1->A and then it's a cell range (A - means the A column)

Comment: Version 1.7.6, 2011-02-27. Yes, the formula is exactly what I put in my example. Thank you!

Comment: Still unable to replicate, though I would suggest you update to a more recent version of PHPExcel if possible.

Comment: Updating to the current version solved  the problem. Thank you :). Do you know where can I find the version number? In PHPExcel.php file there is no number, just: @version    ##VERSION##, ##DATE##

Comment: Did you simply pull from github? If so, then there is no version number anywhere in the code: that's injected by the build process for the production releases from codeplex. The latest develop branch on github is 1.7.9, plus a few additional patches since the production 1.7.9 release (as documented in the changelog)

Comment: I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/MarkBaker/5908357) that can be used to help diagnose calculation engine problems in the future by enabling the calc engine debugger and displaying appropriate outputs

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same error trying to use any math operators such as addition, multiplication, division, or subtraction using PHPExcel version 1.7.6.  I upgrading to the latest version fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's more than two years ago but i have the same error (but just the first, with "...line 2976") and find something for you

> Any idea how to fix it?

@Alexander @Mark Baker
For those who can't update, or for **Mark Baker**, it seems to work with "(" and ")"

So like this :

```
->setCellValue('C1', "=(A1-B1)");
```